# i am facing this error in jupyter notebook,indexError Traceback(list index out of range)

Tags: python, jupyter

I am trying for it to change print title when one wants translation in Shona instead of ndebele

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 40
     38 elif word in translations:
     39     print(f'\nNDEBELE: {translations[word][0]}')
---> 40     print(f'\nSHONA: {translations[word][1]}')
     41 else:
     42     print("\nTranslation unknown.")

IndexError: list index out of range
```

i am trying to get Shona Translation when one types Ndebele words

Comment: Your value of the variable `translations[word]` is of length 1 hence this error.

Comment: Please post a [mre] that shows how you fill in `translations`. This doesn't seem to have anything to do with Jupyter specifically.

Comment: You/we need to know something about `translation`.  Looks like it might be a dict,  where values are lists. Is any of this your own code?